# I can't check any solution for Inet Address in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, network-programming, inetaddress

So I'm trying to get the Ips of the websites on my app and I'm having a lot of problem with this one as a newbie I'm searching everywhere but no clue. I tried on intelij and it works fine while on android it gives hell lot of troubles.

Code:

```
hostnumber = findViewById(R.id.hostnumber);
    output = findViewById(R.id.output);
    submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                InetAddress address = null;
                try {
                    address = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(hostnumber));
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Lookup.this,"Please Check The Url" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                output.setText((CharSequence) address);

            }
        });

    }
});
```

} // on create

I've also added   on the manifest file. I looked Around some old threads but looked up and found that this library has been deprecated into kotlin. Any Idea or solution about this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This line here looks wrong to me: `address = InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(hostnumber));` since it doesn't gat any value from `hostnumber`. Instead, it passes the string representation of the object to `getByName`.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I'm trying to get the Ips of the websites, I see your point do you think doing it directly will solve it? i.e: output.setext(InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(hostnumber));

Comment: No. I assume `hostnumber` is an `EditText`. Therefore, you should use `address = InetAddress.getByName(hostnumber.getText().toString())`.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Still doesn't work

Comment: What is the error that you get? Is an exception thrown?